# how can i use pandas datetools in python because it removed from newer version

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

How can i use pandas datetools in python because it removed from newer version

```
def convert_time(s):
    h, m, s = map(int, s.split(':'))
    return pd.datetools.timedelta(hours=h, minutes=m, seconds=s)
data = pd.read_csv('marathon-data.csv',converters={'split':convert_time, 'final':convert_time})
data.head()
```

Comment: What is your target in the code?

Comment: `pd.Timedelta(hours=h, minutes=m, seconds=s)`?

Comment: If you use the solutions provided (`pd.to_timedelta`), you'll end up with another error related to conversion of the time delta to seconds (assuming you are following [this example](https://books.google.com/books?id=6omNDQAAQBAJ&pg=SA4-PA135&lpg=SA4-PA135)). Then the solution is to adjust again the code: `data['split_sec'] = data['split'].dt.total_seconds()`. You should accept the current answer if it helped.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace your `convert_time()` function with `pd.to_timedelta()`.  It is built in to Pandas and understands HH:MM:SS and similar formats.

Comment: more explicitly: `pd.read_csv('marathon-data.csv', converters={'split':pd.to_timedelta, 'final':pd.to_timedelta}`. Note that `split` is not the string method used in the original custom function, `split` and `final` are the names of columns which need to be converted.

Answer (score 0):

Since `pd.datetools.timedelta` is deprecated, using [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#available-types) is a possible workaround.

Try this updated code snippet:

```
import datetime

def convert_time(s):
    h, m, s = map(int, s.split(':'))
    return datetime.timedelta(hours=h, minutes=m, seconds=s)
data = pd.read_csv('marathon-data.csv',
                    converters={'split':convert_time, 'final':convert_time})
data.head()
```